# howto copy some rows to other ones in mysql

Tags: mysql

can someone say me how can i copy some rows like this:

copy field name from id 1-10 to the id with 31-40

example:

```
1 foo
...
31 bla
```

after that it should be:

```
1 foo
...
31 foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this..

```
UPDATE tablename    
SET fieldname = ( SELECT tablename.fieldname
FROM tablename t2
WHERE t2.id = (tablename.id-30))

WHERE tablename.id BETWEEN 31 AND 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table A
set name = (select B.name from table B where B.Id = A.Id - 30)
where A.id between 31 AND 40
```

Comment: MySQL does not allow you to modify a table from which you're selecting, as it could bad things if you change a field involved in the select

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON A.Id = B.Id + 30
SET A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE A.Id Between 31 and 40
```